# Необходимо получить ответ пользователя в боте ВК

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот, long-poll

Работаю над ботом ВК (использую longpoll). Подскажите, как мне получить только одно сообщение от пользователя (нужно чтобы в основным цикле при определенном условии, цикл останавливался, бот дожидался нового сообщения, потом цикл запускался повторно). Вот мои потуги сделать вышеописанное:

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            usermsg = event.text
            if usermsg = login:
                for event in longpoll.listen():
                    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                        if event.to_me:
                            usermsg2 = event.text
                            if usermsg2 == pass:
                                send(event.user_id, 'login was complete')
                                break
```

или более поздняя попытка

```
def get_message():
    usermsg = ''
    longpoll.listen()
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            usermsg = event.text
    return usermsg

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            usermsg = event.text
            if usermsg = login:
                if get_message() == pass:
                    send(event.user_id, 'login was complete')
                    break
```